# Testing location distance on iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-location

I am calculating speed using `coreLocation`'s `didUpdateToLocation` method, but it is very time-consuming to test calculating the distance on the device every build.

Is there any workaround so that I can get this distance on the simulator?

Comment: Can you show us some code to get an idea of what you are trying to accomplish? From what I understand, I have used `didUpdateToLocation` to find a current location, but not derive distance (and other attributes)

Comment: @kgdesouz , I just want to know that can we pass statically a Co-ordinates  to simulator so that we can get the difference between two points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distance is a question of having two `CLLocation` objects. Then you can simply call:

```
[location1 distanceFromLocation:location2]
```

That'll give you the distance.

If you need to create a location (from a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, for example), you just initialize it with latitude and longitude.

```
[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];
```

If you mean that you wish to have the simulator simulate a specific location, you can create a GPX file and add it to your project. The GPX file format is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx>
    <wpt lat="37.23" lon="-122.444"></wpt>
</gpx>
```

If you add multiple `wpt` items, the simulator will simulate motion between them.

Comment: Yes i wish to simulate a specific location. How can i create a GPX file and does XCode automatically recognize  this file.I hope you understand what i am saying

Comment: Choose 'new file'. Pick 'Resource', then 'GPX file' from the list.

Add the file to your target, and you will be able to select it as a location. If the file has multiple entries, the simulator will simulate motion between them.

Comment: Distance, by the way, is in meters.

Answer (score 1):

in the new XCode you dont need to create a GPX file for simulating your custom location. You need to do the following
1) Select the simulator
2) Select Debug from the menu bar
3) Select Location
4) Custom Location
Thats all